# AdMob + startapp in android?

Tags: android, sdk, admob, ads

i have an app published to the play store with currently integrated the admob SDK.

i'd like to know, it's possible to add also the startapp sdk?
and use all two the ads network?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

StartApp's SDK can definitely be integrated together with Admob's SDK.

Using both ad networks will boost your revenues from your app.

You can find some more information on [startApp's website](http://www.startapp.com/)